# Load image from document directory for iphone in Unity3d

Tags: iphone, ios, web, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

Hi i am working on unity 3d app, i have an url of image and i successfully download image from that url and store into document directory path and path is: /var/mobile/Applications/4EA2C956-FCA1-4552-AEE5-611A55B26CF5/Documents/sample.jpg, now i getting stuck into how to retreive image and show on as a texture i did following code.

```
WWW imageToLoadPath = new WWW(/var/mobile/Applications/4EA2C956-FCA1-4552-AEE5-611A55B26CF5/Documents/sample.jpg) 
//rendering texture 
imageToLoadPath.LoadImageIntoTexture(mIconPlane.renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D);
```

I am getting confuse how to accomplish this task and also i want to do same videos like my path will be **/var/mobile/Applications/4EA2C956-FCA1-4552-AEE5-611A55B26CF5/Documents/sampleVideo.mp4**. 
I only want to do this task in unity 3d and in c sharp.
This will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the documentation Apple have provided regarding accessing files in your App's sandbox including the Document Directory!

Comment: I only want to do this task in unity 3d and in c sharp.

Comment: Seriously i am doing research and googling and also post on unity answer forum here is link "http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/358268/load-image-from-document-directory-for-iphone.html" but still i couldn't get any help.

Comment: It will be great for me that you'll help me because i am stuck over here since last 4 hrs, it already took my a lot time.

Comment: So, what did you find when you Googled for that? And what does it say in the Unity documentation?

Comment: I find that i can directly load image from url thats more easy like "http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html" show, and i also find where someone is loading image here "http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/30147/loading-images-textures-resourcesload-vs-wwwtextur.html" from other path but i couldn't get any healthy information about this task. Actually i am ios developer not unity, its my almost 2 weeks experience in unity so thats why i couldn't understand many things.

Comment: Nick, i am stuck over here still, trying trying and trying, can you please help me on this, i am getting blank texture

Comment: Kindly help me, this will be great for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this codes for load picture from documents directory, i guess you can make it with same codes

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage:(NSString*)imageName {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];

UIImage *graphImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fullPath];
img1.image = graphImage;

return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
}
```

call this method like this

```
[ self loadImage: "your image name"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for getting the document directory path in C# script it might be helpful

```
   public static string GetiPhoneDocumentsPath ()
{
// Application.dataPath returns
// /var/mobile/Applications/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/myappname.app/Data
// Strip "/Data" from path
string path = Application.dataPath.Substring (0, Application.dataPath.Length - 5);
// Strip application name
path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('/'));
return path + "/Documents";
}
```